# phpMyAdmin update to 4.3.6 generates "Undefined index: navwork" error

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just replaced my prior install with PHPMyAdmin 4.3.6 and now I am getting a bunch of notices on my page bottoms that "Undefined index: navwork" is being flagged.

Here is an example:

> Notice in ./libraries/navigation/Nodes/Node_Database.class.php#627
>   Undefined index: navwork
>
> Backtrace
>
> ./libraries/navigation/NavigationTree.class.php#1070:
>   Node_Database->getHtmlForControlButtons()
>   ./libraries/navigation/NavigationTree.class.php#786:
>   PMA_NavigationTree->_renderNode( object, boolean true, )
>   ./libraries/navigation/Navigation.class.php#42:
>   PMA_NavigationTree->renderState() ./libraries/Header.class.php#406:
>   PMA_Navigation->getDisplay() ./libraries/Response.class.php#262:
>   PMA_Header->getDisplay() ./libraries/Response.class.php#275:
>   PMA_Response->_getDisplay() ./libraries/Response.class.php#387:
>   PMA_Response->_htmlResponse()
>   ./libraries/OutputBuffering.class.php#114: PMA_Response::response()
>   PMA_OutputBuffering::stop()

I cannot find a bug report anywhere in PHPMyAdmin site or documentation.

PHP 4.3.7 (unreleased) changelog indicates this is a bug that has been fixed.

Anyone know what this all means, and whether or not I should trust 4.3.6 with my DB setup.

I do believe I have remnants from a poorly uninstalled DB that mayb e part of this problem.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the answer in case someone searches and finds the page.

The error was caused by old data being in the browser cache and in cookies.  I cleaned my browser cache, deleted all domain cookies and session cookies and it went away.

I ran into a horrendous bug in the advanced features configuration:

The build table scripts call for the creation of tables of the form "pma__tablename" while the config script wants to load tables of the form "pma_tablename".  The difference is not readily apparent, but the build file sql script has two underscores.  PhpMyAdmin would complain that the table already existed and would not build the table.  Drove me nuts until I found a post to this effect.

I did a search for "pma__" and replaced all with "pma_" and ran the build tables script and everything settled down.

PhpMyAdmin 4.3.6 is now running smoothly on my local system.

Sorry for the false alarm, but the error message sent me in the wrong direction.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that this bug is critical to the normal function of phpMyAdmin, however, we may never know until someone comments officially about the issue or reports another bug.

Here's some options:

- Wait for the 4.3.7 version to release.
- Revert to a previously stable release without the bug.
- Checkout the [MAINT_4_3_7 branch directly from github](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/tree/MAINT_4_3_7) and use that until its tagged as a release.

MAINT_4_3_7 is passing tests and appears to be working normally as far as I can determine. However, that doesn't mean it's safe/stable -- use at your own risk.