# Reset Status MariaDB

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb

```
Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#564  Undefined index: is_count
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#1999: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#565  Undefined index: is_export
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#1999: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#566  Undefined index: is_func
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#1999: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#567  Undefined index: is_analyse
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#1999: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#568  Undefined index: select_from
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#1999: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#586  Undefined index: is_export
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#2020: PMA_isAppendLimitClause(array) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#587  Undefined index: is_analyse
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#2020: PMA_isAppendLimitClause(array) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#588  Undefined index: select_from
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#2020: PMA_isAppendLimitClause(array) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#589  Undefined index: is_subquery
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#2020: PMA_isAppendLimitClause(array) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#1188  Undefined index: is_affected
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#2037: PMA_executeTheQuery( array, string 'FLUSH STATUS', boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, ) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#604  Undefined index: is_group
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#1197: PMA_isJustBrowsing( array, NULL, ) .\libraries\sql.lib.php#2037: PMA_executeTheQuery( array, string 'FLUSH STATUS', boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, ) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#605  Undefined index: is_func
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#1197: PMA_isJustBrowsing( array, NULL, ) .\libraries\sql.lib.php#2037: PMA_executeTheQuery( array, string 'FLUSH STATUS', boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, ) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#608  Undefined index: select_from
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#1197: PMA_isJustBrowsing( array, NULL, ) .\libraries\sql.lib.php#2037: PMA_executeTheQuery( array, string 'FLUSH STATUS', boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, ) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#586  Undefined index: is_export
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#1063: PMA_isAppendLimitClause(array) .\libraries\sql.lib.php#1200: PMA_countQueryResults( integer 0, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', array, ) .\libraries\sql.lib.php#2037: PMA_executeTheQuery( array, string 'FLUSH STATUS', boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, ) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#587  Undefined index: is_analyse
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#1063: PMA_isAppendLimitClause(array) .\libraries\sql.lib.php#1200: PMA_countQueryResults( integer 0, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', array, ) .\libraries\sql.lib.php#2037: PMA_executeTheQuery( array, string 'FLUSH STATUS', boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, ) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#588  Undefined index: select_from
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#1063: PMA_isAppendLimitClause(array) .\libraries\sql.lib.php#1200: PMA_countQueryResults( integer 0, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', array, ) .\libraries\sql.lib.php#2037: PMA_executeTheQuery( array, string 'FLUSH STATUS', boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, ) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#589  Undefined index: is_subquery
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#1063: PMA_isAppendLimitClause(array) .\libraries\sql.lib.php#1200: PMA_countQueryResults( integer 0, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', array, ) .\libraries\sql.lib.php#2037: PMA_executeTheQuery( array, string 'FLUSH STATUS', boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, ) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#1266  Undefined index: querytype
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#1358: PMA_getMessageForNoRowsReturned( NULL, array, integer 0, ) .\libraries\sql.lib.php#2046: PMA_getQueryResponseForNoResultsReturned( array, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, integer 0, object, NULL, ) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#1268  Undefined index: is_insert
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#1358: PMA_getMessageForNoRowsReturned( NULL, array, integer 0, ) .\libraries\sql.lib.php#2046: PMA_getQueryResponseForNoResultsReturned( array, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, integer 0, object, NULL, ) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, ) Notice in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#1288  Undefined index: is_affected
Backtrace
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#1358: PMA_getMessageForNoRowsReturned( NULL, array, integer 0, ) .\libraries\sql.lib.php#2046: PMA_getQueryResponseForNoResultsReturned( array, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, integer 0, object, NULL, ) .\import.php#786: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false, string 'adventureworks', string '', NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'db_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'FLUSH STATUS', NULL, NULL, )
```

**I get this error when i run 'FLUSH STATUS'**

Comment: What 3rd party software are you running?  Perhaps it is called PMA?

Answer (score 0):

It's PHPMyadmin. Various suggestions I've read on the [phpmyadmin issues tracker](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues) and other [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27951361) suggest clearing your cookies in the browser for the PHPMyAdmin site - and upgrading the version probably won't hurt much either.